# How to move sidebar to the right of dashboard in AdminLTE?

Tags: css, adminlte

How can I move adminlte sidebar to right of the dashboard, without changing functionality?
My adminlte version: v2.4.12.

Comment: isn't it on the left side already? add a screenshot or link to adminlte version you are using so we get more idea

Comment: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Comment: which sidebar you want to move? main sidebar is already on the left. Are you trying to move settings sidebar to left and the main sidebar to right??

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
  <section class="sidebar" dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context on how/where this should be used?

Comment: @StefanKögl, the op must provide some code in order to do that